# Is there a site that fails Chrome's new samesite policy

Tags: google-chrome, samesite

I'm testing a site is unaffected by Chrome's (version 80) new samesite policy. All appears well, and so I wonder if there's a public facing website that clearly fails the new policy so I can confidently confirm the changes I've applied to my `chrome://flags samesite` is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've put together https://samesite-sandbox.glitch.me to validate this. If all rows are green on that site, then the new behaviour is being enforced. 
[image: Chrome 80 screenshot]

Any red or orange and then the browser is not enforcing the new defaults.
[image: iOS12 Safari screenshot]

Comment: Thank you Rowan -- that is brilliant.